# have a local domain rgpd.local for my local app with Kubernetes / Traefik

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

Right now, I can test my local apps with: `http://localhost/rgpd/api/...`

Here is my rgpd-ingress.yaml

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: rgpd-ingress
  namespace: rgpd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /rgpd/api
        backend:
          serviceName: rgpd-api-local
          servicePort: "rgpd-port"
```

I would like to change it to: `rgpd.local`

So I changed it to:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: rgpd-ingress
  namespace: rgpd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rgpd.local
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
         serviceName: rgpd-api-local
         servicePort: "port-rgpd"
```

But now, if I enter old url, I get `404` and I can't connect the new one neither.

Here are my files:

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
  labels:
    app: rgpd-api-local
  name: rgpd-api-local
  namespace: rgpd
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rgpd-api-local
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: rgpd_api:local
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: rgpd-env
          name: rgpd-api-local
          ports:
            - containerPort: 10000
```

And service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rgpd-api-local
  name: rgpd-api-local
  namespace: rgpd
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "rgpd-port"
    port: 10000
  selector:
    app: rgpd-api-local
```

Why can't it work ?

Comment: post the output of `ping rgpd.local`

Comment: @PalashGoel ping: rgpd.local: Name or service not known

Comment: Add an entry in hosts file: /etc/hosts. rgpd.local 127.0.0.1

Comment: Yep, it did the trick! I forgot that. Now I have a service unavailable, but this is another issue !

Comment: @PalashGoel you can put it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an entry in hosts file: 
/etc/hosts
`rgpd.local 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

update `/etc/hosts` or just supply Host header i.e `curl -H "Host: rgpd.local" 127.0.0.1`